# Can't use pip after download?

Tags: python, django, pip

This is how I downloaded pip:

- I installed https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and placed it in the scripts subdirectory of Python.
- Then I ensured that the scripts subdirectory was a part of my system path.
- Next I used command prompt to navigate to the file and ran it.
- It downloaded and installed `pip` successfully (As far as I could tell).

My problem is that now when I try to use the `pip install Django==1.6.5` command, it says `pip` is not recognized as an internal or external command.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that I was adding **;C:\Python\Scripts** to the system variables PATH.

Adding this to the user variables PATH resolved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

Did you check if you have pip.exe's parent directory added to your "Environment variables" paths?

You can use this page to consult on how to check / change / add / delete environment variable paths. [How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Basically what you have to do is

1. Find `pip.exe`, which is most likely in `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe`
2. Add it's parent directory (eg. `C:\Python27\Scripts`) in the Environment Variable paths.

Now you should be able to run commands using pip such as `pip install httpie`.

Hopefully the matter is resolved for you.

Comment: Yeah, I've done this already S: no luck

Comment: Im going to go ahead and try a system restart

Comment: You must reboot after that :)

Comment: Still no good )= , any other ideas?

Comment: Ok go to the pip.exe directory and open your command shell there and then execute the command. See if that helps. If that works, then you might have to recheck you environment paths.

Comment: Still nope S: This is the worst haha

Comment: Do you even have pip in your Python/Scripts directory? Because otherwise that means, the installation didn't go right.

Comment: Yeah its there, It ended up in Python27\Lib\site-packages... and I tried to add that to the Path as well... no luck

Comment: Try this instead for both Python27/Scripts and Python27/Lib/site-packages directories

Type the following in your command prompt and then run pip
 [ setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts" ]